# Shopify cart API - remove product after given time period

Tags: javascript, cookies, shopify, liquid

The problem I am encountering is as follows:

Platform: Shopify website
Challenge: Remove item from cart after given time (1 hour in this case)

Current solution:

```
 let product = document.querySelectorAll('.product-cart-item');
    let btn = document.getElementById('AddToCart');
    
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        for (const prod of product) {
        prodId = prod.getAttribute('product-id');
    }
        setTimeout(() => {
        jQuery.post('/cart/change.js', { quantity: 0, id: prodId })
    }, 3600000);
    })
```

Problem with solution:

Using setTimeout is not ideal as there is no guarantee the user has the website open for the entire period of time.

How can I implement the same solution but via a cookie or something along those lines?

I used the Shopify Cart API to make a call the the /cart/change.js endpoint, update the quantity of the line item and remove it from the cart.

The expected result is to have the product removed from the cart, which happens. But as the time period given, is 1 hour, I expect I will need to use local storage to achieve the result I'm getting.

Comment: without going into server side solutions, you can add a line property with the time and thus checking it every minute or so and update the cart when needed